# EOFerror when reading a pickle file from a subprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, temporary-files

So I'm using Python's cPickle and the multiprocessing module to create a dictionary in a subprocess, save it to a `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`, dump the dictionary using cPickle and load the pickle in the parent process.

I've used cPickle/pickle before so I know about using the `"wb"` and `"rb"` modes properly.
This does not seem to be a problem. I create the `NamedTemporaryFile` in the parent process and pickle to it in the child process.

It's getting an `EOFError` when I try to load the pickle in the parent.
Any ideas?

Comment: 1. Could you show the file? 2. Using the file as communication means between parent and child can be replaced by using the multiprocessing queue or other objects specially for this purpose. 3. Is the file deleted after the child closes?

Comment: I think I've fixed it. I put in calls to flush() and close() in the subprocess so I'm not sure which one does the trick. I believe that close() by itself wasn't doing it early on, but now it seems that I can't recreate it.